# location.reload() no me funciona?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de hacer que, con un botón, `parsee` un contenido de un textarea y luego haga un reload de la propia página para borrar el contenido del formulario que tenga escrito:

```js
// LOAD
// Cuando la pagina carga tambien cargan las templates
// y se integran en el formulario
   window.addEventListener("load",()=>{
      
         // metemos las estructuras de los templates gracias a innerHTML dentro de variables
      var temCard    = document.querySelector("#temp-card").innerHTML;
      var temPower   = document.querySelector("#temp-power").innerHTML;
      var temEnergy  = document.querySelector("#temp-energy").innerHTML;

         // hacemos una seleccion del div #content-form
      var contentForm   = document.querySelector("#content-form");

         // Creamos los div corresponidentes asignandoles a cada uno
         // su template concreta
      let card = document.createElement("div");
      card.innerHTML = temCard
      contentForm.appendChild(card);
      let power = document.createElement("div");
      power.innerHTML = temPower;

      let energy = document.createElement("div");
      energy.innerHTML = temEnergy;

         // Metemos dentro de los container los hijos power y energy
         // anteriormente definidos
      card.querySelector(".container-power").appendChild(power);
      card.querySelector(".container-energy").appendChild(energy);
   });

//      BTN ADD BUTTON V_POWER

function addPower(el)   {
   var temPower   = document.querySelector("#temp-power").innerHTML;

   let power = document.createElement("div");
   power.innerHTML = temPower;
   el.querySelector(".container-power").appendChild(power);

}
//       BTN ADD BUTTON V_ENERGY
function addEnergy(el)  {
   var temEnergy  =  document.querySelector('#temp-energy').innerHTML;

   let energy = document.createElement('div');
   energy.innerHTML = temEnergy;
   el.querySelector('.container-energy').appendChild(energy);
}

//       BTN ADD TEMPLATE FORM
function addFrm() {
   var tmp = document.querySelector('#temp-card').innerHTML;
 
   var cont = document.querySelector('#content-form')
   let frm = document.createElement('div');


   frm.innerHTML = tmp;
   cont.appendChild(frm);
   addPower(frm)
   addEnergy(frm)
}

//    BTN LECTURA VALORES INPUT

function sndFrm()   {
      // Hacer una variable con formato JSON vacio

   var jotason = [];
      // Seleccionar TODOS los templatecARD con el bucle forEach
   document.body.querySelectorAll(".templatecARD").forEach(form=>{

            // Metemos dentro de la variable obj la estructura del title
            // asignando a title el valor del input .name_tarif
         let obj = {
            title : form.querySelector(".name_tarif").value
         };
         // power
         let power = {};
         form.querySelectorAll("input[name=t_power]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
            var ob = power[index]||{};
            ob.type=inpt.value;
            power[index]=ob;
         });
         form.querySelectorAll("input[name=v_power]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
            var ob = power[index]||{};
            ob.value=inpt.value;
            power[index]=ob;
         });

         // energy
         let energy = {};
         form.querySelectorAll("input[name=t_energy]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
            var oj = energy[index]||{};
            oj.type=inpt.value;
            energy[index]=oj;
         });
         form.querySelectorAll("input[name=v_energy]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
            var oj = energy[index]||{};
            oj.value=inpt.value;
            energy[index]=oj;
         });
         obj.power = power;
         obj.energy = energy;
         jotason.push(obj);

   });


      // Hacer un string del JSON jotason [fil:69]
   var jsoned = JSON.stringify(jotason,undefined, 2);
      // Meter dentro del textarea con id txtare el valor 
      // de jotason [fil:69]
   document.getElementById('txtare').value=jsoned;
}

function sndTo(){
  var pJsn = document.getElementById('txtare').value;

  JSON.parse(pJsn, function (){
     console.log('hola dentro');
     location.reload();
     return false;
  });
   console.log('hola');
}
```

```css
form{
    float: left;
}
.templatecARD{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 15px;
}
.jsn_edit{
    width: 350px;
    margin-top: 14px;
    float: left;
}
textarea{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LOGOS Energía</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>


<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<template id="temp-card">
 
     <div class="templatecARD" data-group="0" >
        <label>Tarif</label>
        <input type="text" class="name_tarif" name="tarif"/>
        
        <div>
            <div class="container-power"></div>
            <button type="button" onclick="addPower(this.parentNode)">+</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="container-energy" ></div>
            <button type="button" onclick="addEnergy(this.parentNode)">+</button>
        </div>

    </div>


</template> 
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<template  id="temp-power">
    <div class="box-power" >
        <label>Power</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="t_power" style="width:40px" />
            <input type="text" name="v_power"/>
        </div>
    </div>

</template> 
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<template  id="temp-energy">
    <div class="box-energy" >
        <label>Energy</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="t_energy" style="width:40px" />
            <input type="text" name="v_energy"/>
        </div>
    </div>

</template> 
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->


    <!-- FORMULARIO -->
        <!-- FORMULARIO -->
            <!-- FORMULARIO -->
<form method="post">

    <div id="content-form">

    </div>
        
    <div>
        <button type="button" onclick="sndFrm()">UPDATE TEXTAREA</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="addFrm()">+</button>
    </div>
</form>
            <!-- FORMULARIO -->
        <!-- FORMULARIO -->
    <!-- FORMULARIO -->


    <!-- EDITOR DE JSON -->
<div class="jsn_edit">
<textarea id="txtare" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></textarea>

<button type="button" onclick="sndTo()">UPDATE FORM</button>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Pero no consigo por ninguna manera hacer correctamente el reload.
¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Porque según la documentación es (o debe ser) tan básico como un alert...

He probado con:

`window.location.reload();`
`location.reload(); return false`
`location.reload();`
`reload()`

Y no encuentro otra forma de hacerlo, así que, una de dos, o asumo que el error viene a la hora de parsearlo, que no lo haga y no continue con la `function`, o bien no se cómo hacer un `reload()`.

**[EDIT]**

He cambiado el código de la máquina, ya me funciona el reload correctamente salvo por el pequeño detalle que me hace un reload 18 veces. ¿Por qué, si no hay ni un solo bucle? No lo se. Pero es así.

Comment: El problema debe de venirte de otro lado. La consola del navegador te debe de estar arrojando un error que te de más pistas al respecto. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta para añadirlo?

Comment: Que va, no me arrojaba absolutamente nada, porque probe con console.logs a ver dónde dejaba de imprimir, y era porque cerraba la función antes de ejecutar nada. Ahora ya lo ejecuta. ¿Problema? Lo hace entre 16 y 18 veces XD

Comment: ¿Lo sigue haciendo 18 veces? Pulsa en [edit] y muestra cómo quedó el código ahora, así podremos verificar. Y, como dice @phpMyGuel el problema podría venir también de otro lado, por ejemplo, de otros archivos que incluyes.

Comment: @Aaronibio, para saber porque se ejecuta 18 veces, te recomiendo leer como funciona el parámetro [`reviver` de `JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse#ejemplo_usando_el_par%C3%A1metro_reviver)

Comment: No, ya encontré el problema. Le problema vino del `JSON.parse(Pjsn)`, ya que, estaba parseando directamente TODO el contenido del textarea. Es decir, la primera apertura de llave me la asignaba como un valor directamente.
Ahora pondré la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias @Marcos, ya lo vi, ahora actualizo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema viene de:

```
function sndTo(){
  var pJsn = document.getElementById('txtare').value;

  JSON.parse(pJsn, function (){  //ESTA LINEA
     console.log('hola dentro');
     location.reload();
     return false;
  });
   console.log('hola');
}
```

La parsear de esta manera `pJsn`, lo que hacía es que, el valor del textarea, aunque fuera un formato JSON, lo estaba parseando todo, por tanto, desde la primera apertura de llave hasta la última, lo estaba metiendo como objetos.

Lo que se hizo fue el siguiente cambio:

```
function sndTo(){
      var pJsn = document.getElementById('txtare').value;
      var dat  = JSON.parse(pJsn);
      for(let n in dat){
         (form=>{

            console.log(form);
         })(dat[n])
      }
}
```

Parseándolo y metiéndolo como variable, después agregar un bucle con el valor n y añadiendo una variable anónima vacía, con eso conseguí meter todos los formularios que quisiera dentro de arrays independientes.

```js
// LOAD
// Cuando la pagina carga tambien cargan las templates
// y se integran en el formulario
   window.addEventListener("load",()=>{
      
         // metemos las estructuras de los templates gracias a innerHTML dentro de variables
      var temCard    = document.querySelector("#temp-card").innerHTML;
      var temPower   = document.querySelector("#temp-power").innerHTML;
      var temEnergy  = document.querySelector("#temp-energy").innerHTML;

         // hacemos una seleccion del div #content-form
      var contentForm   = document.querySelector("#content-form");

         // Creamos los div corresponidentes asignandoles a cada uno
         // su template concreta
      let card = document.createElement("div");
      card.innerHTML = temCard
      contentForm.appendChild(card);
      let power = document.createElement("div");
      power.innerHTML = temPower;

      let energy = document.createElement("div");
      energy.innerHTML = temEnergy;

         // Metemos dentro de los container los hijos power y energy
         // anteriormente definidos
      card.querySelector(".container-power").appendChild(power);
      card.querySelector(".container-energy").appendChild(energy);
   });

//      BTN ADD BUTTON V_POWER

function addPower(el)   {
   var temPower   = document.querySelector("#temp-power").innerHTML;

   let power = document.createElement("div");
   power.innerHTML = temPower;
   el.querySelector(".container-power").appendChild(power);

}
//       BTN ADD BUTTON V_ENERGY
function addEnergy(el)  {
   var temEnergy  =  document.querySelector('#temp-energy').innerHTML;

   let energy = document.createElement('div');
   energy.innerHTML = temEnergy;
   el.querySelector('.container-energy').appendChild(energy);
}

//       BTN ADD TEMPLATE FORM
function addFrm() {
   var tmp = document.querySelector('#temp-card').innerHTML;
 
   var cont = document.querySelector('#content-form')
   let frm = document.createElement('div');


   frm.innerHTML = tmp;
   cont.appendChild(frm);
   addPower(frm)
   addEnergy(frm)
}

//    BTN LECTURA VALORES INPUT

function sndFrm()   {
      // Hacer una variable con formato JSON vacio

   var jotason = [];
      // Seleccionar TODOS los templatecARD con el bucle forEach
   document.body.querySelectorAll(".templatecARD").forEach(form=>{

            // Metemos dentro de la variable obj la estructura del title
            // asignando a title el valor del input .name_tarif
         let obj = {
            title : form.querySelector(".name_tarif").value
         };
         // power
         let power = {};
         form.querySelectorAll("input[name=t_power]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
            var ob = power[index]||{};
            ob.type=inpt.value;
            power[index]=ob;
         });
         form.querySelectorAll("input[name=v_power]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
            var ob = power[index]||{};
            ob.value=inpt.value;
            power[index]=ob;
         });

         // energy
         let energy = {};
         form.querySelectorAll("input[name=t_energy]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
            var oj = energy[index]||{};
            oj.type=inpt.value;
            energy[index]=oj;
         });
         form.querySelectorAll("input[name=v_energy]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
            var oj = energy[index]||{};
            oj.value=inpt.value;
            energy[index]=oj;
         });
         obj.power = power;
         obj.energy = energy;
         jotason.push(obj);

   });


      // Hacer un string del JSON jotason [fil:69]
   var jsoned = JSON.stringify(jotason,undefined, 2);
      // Meter dentro del textarea con id txtare el valor 
      // de jotason [fil:69]
   document.getElementById('txtare').value=jsoned;
}

function sndTo(){
      var pJsn = document.getElementById('txtare').value;
      var dat  = JSON.parse(pJsn);
      for(let n in dat){
         (form=>{

            console.log(form);
         })(dat[n])
      }
}
```

```css
form{
    float: left;
}
.templatecARD{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 15px;
}
.jsn_edit{
    width: 350px;
    margin-top: 14px;
    float: left;
}
textarea{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LOGOS Energía</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>


<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<template id="temp-card">
 
     <div class="templatecARD" data-group="0" >
        <label>Tarif</label>
        <input type="text" class="name_tarif" name="tarif"/>
        
        <div>
            <div class="container-power"></div>
            <button type="button" onclick="addPower(this.parentNode)">+</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="container-energy" ></div>
            <button type="button" onclick="addEnergy(this.parentNode)">+</button>
        </div>

    </div>


</template> 
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<template  id="temp-power">
    <div class="box-power" >
        <label>Power</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="t_power" style="width:40px" />
            <input type="text" name="v_power"/>
        </div>
    </div>

</template> 
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<template  id="temp-energy">
    <div class="box-energy" >
        <label>Energy</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="t_energy" style="width:40px" />
            <input type="text" name="v_energy"/>
        </div>
    </div>

</template> 
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->


    <!-- FORMULARIO -->
        <!-- FORMULARIO -->
            <!-- FORMULARIO -->
<form method="post">

    <div id="content-form">

    </div>
        
    <div>
        <button type="button" onclick="sndFrm()">UPDATE TEXTAREA</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="addFrm()">+</button>
    </div>
</form>
            <!-- FORMULARIO -->
        <!-- FORMULARIO -->
    <!-- FORMULARIO -->


    <!-- EDITOR DE JSON -->
<div class="jsn_edit">
<textarea id="txtare" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></textarea>

<button type="button" onclick="sndTo()">UPDATE FORM</button>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Realmente, parece que el primer código no parseaba nada, no hay nada referente al formulario en ese código, lo que sí, se llamaba el reload desde dentro del parseo, lo cual es un error. Y, viendo que es un formulario, me pregunto por qué mejor no usaste `FormData` para esto ¿?

Comment: Estoy aprendiendo y no conocía FormData, voy a echarle un vistazo, muchas gracias =3

Comment: [Mira en esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46774073/5587982) un ejemplo. Con dos líneas de código conviertes un formulario en JSON.